# Driver : delta Z between two bones?

Tags: bones, drivers

I want to drive a bone X rotation with a value based on two other bones Z position

[image]

TargetBone.rotation.x = BoneA.location.Z - BoneB.location.Z

[image]

but I dont understand how to do that with dirvers

it is asking for a path, but how do I find the path ?

do I have to use a property ? then how do I update that property from that delta Z ?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a driver like this (be aware, i didn't use your properties/axis you have to adapt that, but it is similar)

[image]

You start by right click on rotation value of the bone in pose mode and choose "add driver".

For a simple driver like this you would use transform channel. Here you can choose the type and the space. So you won't have the problem with data path.

Press the "add input variable" button to add a new property and choose your other bone. I have renamed them to y1 and y2 to differentiate between them easily.

Note: if you ever need to know the data path, you can just right click in a field and then choose "copy data path". Then you can paste that data path whereever you need that data path.

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: thanks, I indeed figured it out in the end :-)

Comment: Great!! Glad it worked for you